# Git ignores reverted changes on branch when merging to master

Tags: git, gitlab

Let's say I have the branch "staging" and I had created some files on it and committed them. I merged the "staging" branch to master accidentally.

Because it was too soon to merge (I still had work to do on the "staging" branch), I tried to revert the merge commit (using `git revert`; I don't know the exact command because I used PyCharm's Git UI). Now those changes are reverted on the "master" branch and everything's good.

After finishing my work on the "staging" branch, I tried to merge it to master using these commands:

```
git checkout master
git pull
git merge staging
```

And this is git's response:

```
Auto-merging app/static/css/style.bundle.rtl.css
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in app/static/css/style.bundle.rtl.css
Removing app/static/js/main.js
Removing app/static/css/util.css
..
(All of my new files were listed here as removed)
..
Removing app/static/css/main.css
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

Because of that old merge commit's reversion, git has detected all my changes on pre-existing files as conflicts and deleted all new files.

I aborted this operation by `git merge --abort`, and now my files are all back. But I'm stuck and cannot merge this branch into master. What should I do?

I tried:

- Merging using `git merge staging -X theirs`, but this ignored all changes that have been made on master by other developers
- Merging from the other hand: `git checkout staging && git merge master -s ours`, same problem as above

Comment: re-revert the commit (on the original branch) and then merge again

Comment: Probably try forcing it adding to the command `-f`

Comment: @knittl how should I do that so my git repo stays safe? I don't know the exact command

Comment: @AnkushVerma Wouldn't it create the same problem? Ignoring all changes that have been made on master by others...

Comment: You can try `git reset --hard` (on master) to the commit before the first merge.

Comment: @ykaner This approach also won’t work if any other commits have been created since the merge; moving the refs would effectively lose those changes.

Comment: @AnkushVerma It's possible to fix using `git rebase`. Any way re-reverting as @knittl wrote will work.

Comment: @knittl Thank you; Your solution is working. I simply reverted that commit with `git revert` and then those branches merged as usual. Please post your answer so that I could mark it as accepted.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have the time to write a proper answer before and thought I'd just drop the comment in case it helps or somebody else wanted to provide a full answer. Added the answer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you revert, you tell Git that you don't want these changes (ever (again)). This also means that merging a branch with a revert will remove those changes or not merge them again.

In other words: when merging, only "new" changes are merged, not old ones (i.e. changes before a branch started).

If you decide that you actually need the reverted changes, you have to revert the revert, e.g.

```
git checkout branch
git revert hash-of-revert-commit
git checkout master
git merge branch
```